# How to add ads in SharePoint hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

How can we add ads (eg Google adsense) to SharePoint hosted app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Google adsense. However, I have used ads from [Developer Media](http://developermedia.com/) previously and am currently using ads from [SharePoint ads](http://www.sharepointads.com/) in my blog. Normally, they give you an HTML ad code and the instructions for pasting the code in the pages. The ad code of developer media used to be a `div` tag with some publisher specific details where as SharePoint ads uses a `script` tag. So, if you want to show ads in a SharePoint hosted app, you can get the HTML code from adsense and add it to the app pages.

Comment: Hi Nadeem, Is there any other reliable advertisment network than google-adsense? example sharepointadds.com etc.

How to add ads from other if any ?

Comment: @PrasadGavande, actually I had added that info first, then thought of removing it. Anyways, I have rolled it back.